# Iteration beyond while and maphash?

Tags: emacs, elisp, iteration

I'm trying to write a small system of macros to do iterative tasks in Emacs Lisp. I had taken it for granted that there is nothing beyond `while` loop. No more primitives or some hidden features, but I decided, I'd better ask.

By "hidden features" I mean something akin to [`tagbody`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_tagbod.htm#tagbody) in Common Lisp, i.e. the very primitive form to model the code in terms of blocks, jumps and labels. Are there any such thing in eLisp? Not even in any "hackish" way, like, for example, through the bytecode? Of course, I know about `(catch ... (throw ... ))` construct, but it is not quite the same, because it only allows jumping "backwards", but never forward. I also assumed it is a rather complex construct, not suitable for building fast iteration primitives.

Another thing that bugs me is that there doesn't seem to be a way to create an iterator for hash-tables. I.e. a hash-table must be itereated using `maphash` and once you exit the `maphash` function, there's no coming back to where you left it. So far I understand, it has to do something like, exporting a vector of keys and a vector of values and iterating over these, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get hold of these vectors / lists / whichever those are. Or am I again wrong?

I've looked into how `cl` package generates code for `loop` and `dotimes` / `dolist` / `do`, but they just use `while` or `maphash`, whichever is appropriate, and, frankly, I'm not so fond of their code... More than that, if, say, in the `loop` there are two `for-as-hash` clauses, they simply ignore the first (you don't even get a warning for that) and generate code for the second :|

Any chance there are some tricks to get hold of these iteration primitives from the user code in eLisp? If not, how feasible it is, and is it really, to write an extension in C?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but if you're contemplating writing C extensions, then clearly convenience for the end user isn't a huge concern. Why not just pull in `cl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Other looping constructs?

The only general-purpose built-in looping construct in Emacs Lisp is `while` (see [`eval.c`](https://github.com/emacsmirror/emacs/blob/master/src/eval.c#L822)). The macros `dolist` and `dotimes` ([in `subr.el`](https://github.com/emacsmirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/subr.el#L198)) are both implemented using `while`.

There are also built-in functions for mapping over various data structures: `mapatoms`, `mapc`, `mapcar`, `map-char-table`, `mapconcat`, `maphash`, and `map-keymap`. But these are implemented in such a way that you can't interleave their execution with other Lisp code (see for example [`maphash` in `fns.c`](https://github.com/emacsmirror/emacs/blob/master/src/fns.c#L4469)). If you want to loop over two such data structures, you have to loop over one and then over the other.

So I think you're basically out of luck.

#### 2. Extensions?

Emacs is deliberately designed not to have dynamic C-level extensions, to make it more difficult for someone to mount an "[embrace and extend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend_and_extinguish)" attack on the freedom of Emacs users (see the emacs-devel thread [starting here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2003-07/msg00398.html), for example).

So if you want to add C-level functionality, you have to edit the source code. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can `tagbody` as a macro:

```
   (defmacro cl-tagbody (&rest tags-or-stmts)
     (let ((blocks '()))
       (let ((block (list 'cl--preamble)))
         (dolist (tag-or-stmt tags-or-stmts)
           (if (consp tag-or-stmt) (push tag-or-stmt block)
             ;; Add a "go to next block" to implement the fallthrough.
             (push (nreverse (cons `(go ,tag-or-stmt) block)) blocks)
             (setq block (list tag-or-stmt))))
         (push (nreverse (cons `(go cl--exit) block)) blocks))
       (let ((catch-tag (make-symbol "cl--tagbody-tag")))
         (macroexpand-all
          `(let ((next-tag 'cl--preamble))
             (while
                 (not (eq (setq next-tag
                                (catch ',catch-tag
                                  (cl-case next-tag
                                    ,@blocks)))
                          'cl--exit))))
          `((go . (lambda (tag) `(throw ',catch-tag ',tag)))
            ,@macroexpand-all-environment)))))
```